# Drop Duplicate rows (Summarizing the data) in pandas dataframe based on condition and other columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, nan

I have a dataframe `df` as below:

```
Student_ID   Subject     Weekly_Feedback        Feedack_questions            Exam_Phase
100101       Physics       Excellent: 5         How was physics class?       Mid term
100101         NaN         NaN                  how was physics class?       Final
100101       Physics       Good: 3              How was the Presentation?    Final
100101         NaN         Excellent: 5         How Much would you rate?     Mid term
100102         NaN         NaN                  how much would you rate?     Mid term 
100102       Chemistry     Good: 3              How was chemistry class?     Final
100102         NaN         Good: 3              How was over all experience? Mid term
100102         NaN         very Good: 3         How was topics explained?    Final
100102         NaN         NaN                  How did the class go?        Mid term
100103       Mathematics   NaN                  NaN                          Final
100103       Mathematics   Good :4              NaN                          Final
```

I want to summarize the data in such a way that for every `Student_ID` there must be only one record(row) each containing `Exam_Phase` as **Final** and **Mid Term**, if a `Stundet_ID` has only one `Exam_Phase` then only that needs to be considered. The rows must be selected so as to contain least minimum  `NaN` as possible
(**E.g:** In last 4 rows of dataframe, i.e:

```
Student_ID    Subject     Weekly_Feedback       Feedack_questions            Exam_Phase
100102       Chemistry     Good: 3              How was chemistry class?     Final
100102         NaN         Good: 3              How was over all experience? Mid term
100102         NaN         very Good: 3         How was topics explained?    Final
100102         NaN         NaN                  How did the class go?        Mid Term
```

for `Student_ID` = `100102`, This row:

```
100102         NaN         Good: 3              How was over all experience? Mid term
```

has to be selected as this row has less `NaN` values (in only one of the column) when `Exam_Phase` = `Mid term`. )

The **Output** dataframe should look like this:

```
Student_ID   Subject     Weekly_Feedback        Feedack_questions             Exam_Phase
100101       Physics       Excellent: 5         How was physics class?        Mid term
100101       Physics       Good: 3              How was the Presentation?     Final
100102       Chemistry     Good: 3              How was chemistry class?      Final
100102         NaN         Good: 3              How was over all experience?  Mid term
100103       Mathematics   Good :4              NaN                           Final
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`panda.DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html):

```
(df.groupby(["Student_ID", "Exam_Phase"])
    .apply(lambda x:
        x.iloc[x.isnull().sum(axis = 1).argmin()]
    )
)
```

PD: I posted it in multiple lines to improve readability but you can put it all in one line.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way using `series.argsort` then `df.query` for filtering and `drop_duplicates`

```
l = ['Final','Mid term']
out = (df.loc[df.isna().sum(1).argsort()].query("Exam_Phase in @l")
                      .drop_duplicates(["Student_ID",'Exam_Phase']))
```

---

```
print(out)

    Student_ID      Subject Weekly_Feedback             Feedack_questions  \
0       100101      Physics    Excellent: 5        How was physics class?   
2       100101      Physics         Good: 3     How was the Presentation?   
5       100102    Chemistry         Good: 3      How was chemistry class?   
6       100102          NaN         Good: 3  How was over all experience?   
10      100103  Mathematics         Good :4                           NaN   

   Exam_Phase  
0    Mid term  
2       Final  
5       Final  
6    Mid term  
10      Final
```